# My Http method doesnt appear in swaggerUI

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi

I have 2 controller classes and one of them works fine but another doesn't appear in Swagger when I run `dotnet watch run`.

This is the one that's  not working:

```
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class PolicaController : ControllerBase
{
    public Context Context {get; set;}
    public PolicaController(Context context){Context=context;}

    [Route("DodajPolicu/{idKluba}/{oznaka}/{max}/{trenutno}")]
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult> DodajPolicu(int idKluba, string oznaka, int max, int trenutno)
    {
        if (trenutno > max) 
            return BadRequest("Neodgovarajuci parametri!");

        var Klub = Context.Klubovi
                          .Where(k => k.ID == idKluba)
                          .FirstOrDefault();

        if (Klub == null) 
             return BadRequest("Nepostojeci klub!");

        var provera = Context.Police
                             .Where(p => p.Oznaka == oznaka)
                             .FirstOrDefault();

        if (provera != null) 
            return BadRequest("Polica sa ovom oznakom vec postoji!");

        Polica p = new Polica();
        p.VideoKlub = Klub;
        p.Oznaka = oznaka;

        if (max <= 0) 
            p.Maksimum = 10;
        else 
            p.Maksimum = max;

        if (trenutno <= 0) 
            p.Trenutno = 5;
        else 
            p.Trenutno = trenutno;

        try
        {
            Context.Police.Add(p);
            await Context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return Ok(p);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            return BadRequest(e.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My file didnt have extension .cs,
Great.